# The city the closest to Istanbul

Tags: grammar, adjectives, superlative-degree, adjective-position

I see some examples with adjectives taking place after nouns they define like

- I want to go to a city close to Istanbul
- Have you ever had a friend kind to you?

But what about their -st or -most(superlative) ones?
Are sentences below grammatically OK?

- I want to go to the city the closest to Istanbul?(The longest version is "the city that is the closest to Istanbul")
- Who was your friend the kindest to you?

I know we can say "the closest city to Istanbul" or "the kindest friend  to you" but I'm asking about the ones above.
Thanks

Comment: "A friend kind to you" is ungrammatical.  It would be "A friend *be* kind to you".  Similar problems apply to your superlative.  "Which friend was kindest to you?".  The city ones are fine.

Comment: First, @DanBron is right. "A friend kind to you" is ungrammatical. An adjective that properly appears after a noun is called a **post-positive adjective**, so you may want to research that topic. However, in response to your question, yes, you can properly say, "I want to go to the city *closest* to Istanbul," though you'll notice I've omitted the "the" you put between "city" and "closest" as it's incorrect.